# Exporting VBA sql Excel query to csv

Tags: excel, vba

Using the next code I am able to do some basic sql queries against an excel sheet. Now, I need to export the whole result set (assigned to the variable result) into a CSV file. How can I do this?

```
Sub MyMethod()
   '--- Declare Variables to store the connection, the result and the SQL query
   Dim connection As Object, result As Object, sql As String, recordCount As Integer
   '--- Connect to the current datasource of the Excel file
   Set connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With connection
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
End With



'--- Write the SQL Query. In this case, we are going to select manually the data range
'--- To print the whole information of the table

'-- full_name = [first name] + " " + [last name]


sql = "SELECT [id], [first name], [last name], [salary], [tax], [salary] - [tax] as saldo, [first name] & chr(32) & [last name] as fullInfo FROM [miTabla1$A1:E3]"
      

'--- Run the SQL query
Set result = connection.Execute(sql)


For i = 0 To result.Fields.Count - 1
   Debug.Print result.Fields(i).Name
Next i



'--- Fetch information
Do
    ' Print the information of every column of the result
    
    
    Debug.Print result(0); ";" & result(1) & ";" & result(2) & ";" & result(3) & ";" & result(4); ";" & result(5) & ";" & result(6)
    result.MoveNext
    recordCount = recordCount + 1
Loop Until result.EOF

'--- Print the amount of results
Debug.Print vbNewLine & recordCount & " results found."


End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give as parameters the result object and a string with the full path to create the csv file eg. "C:\TESTS\FIRST.CSV" (csv is a text file -comma separated values-)

```
Option Explicit

Sub createCSVfile(ByRef result, filePath As String)
   Dim FSO As Object, csvFile As Object
   Const litSeparator = ";"   'OR USE "," ACCORDING YOUR REGIONAL SETTINGS
   Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set csvFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(filePath)
   Do While Not result.EOF
      
       csvFile.WriteLine result(0) & litSeparator & result(1) & litSeparator & result(2) & litSeparator & _
                        result(3) & litSeparator & result(4) & litSeparator & result(5) & litSeparator & result(6)
       result.MoveNext
   Loop
   csvFile .Close
   Set FSO = Nothing
   Set csvFile = Nothing
End Sub
```